# Iterate through users and display users meta info at front-page

Tags: custom-field, users

I have a meta field in user called `columnista-destacado` I need to iterate through Wordpress users and if that field has valued set (lets said equal 1) then I need to display user meta info at front-page. Should be 6 users at maximum, how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is more useful to look at the task outside of the WordPress field, but from true programming. 
You can use custom SQL query to get your users ids and then do what you want with them.

Place the code below into `functions.php`

```
function wpse_177536_get_user_ids(){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='columnista-destacado' AND  meta_value = '1' LIMIT 6";
    $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
    return $user_ids;
}
```

Now anywhere, for example, in `front-page.php` you can call this function like this:

```
$user_ids = wpse_177536_get_user_ids();
```

Comment: And it's recommended do in that way in a common `front-page.php` file?

Comment: It is recomended to wrap this code in a function and move it in `functions.php`. In `front-page.php` call the function to get your users ids.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show me how to do that? I'm not so expert at WP this are my first steps

Comment: I've updated the post, as you asked.